# mobx: отслеживать изменение данных в хранилище

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

у меня есть хранилище данных `store` в которые мой компонент (`react`) вносит данные

у компонента есть кнопка `apply`, которую хотелось бы делать активной, только когда внесенные данные корректны, т.е.

```
class Element_Apply extends Component<any> {

    // отрисовка компонента
    render() {

        return (
<div className = 'element-apply'>
    <button disabled = {this.props.store.check()}>Применить</button>
</div>
        );
    }
}
```

где функция `check()` - функция в хранилище, которая проверяет данные на корректность

данным в хранилище записываются так:

```
this.props.store['название поля'] = value;
```

название полей может быть произвольными

Как мне сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от того, что выдает функция `check()` активировать или деактивировать кнопку.

Т.е. надо сделать так, чтобы когда изменялись данные в `store` выполнялась проверка `check()` и, если требуется, то перерисовывалась бы кнопка.

P.S.

попытался сделать это через отслеживаемую переменную

```
@observable private m_checked: boolean = false;
```

реакцию на изменение всего хранилища:

```
   reaction(
        () => this,
        () => {
            m_checked = xxx;
        }
   );
```

и функцию

```
check(): boolean {

    return this.m_checked;

}
```

, но реакция не сработала и вообще мне кажется, что запутался и ваяю костыль жуткий :(